# Using IOpenService::SetDefault to change the default search engine on Microsoft Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I currently use this API to purpose the user my custom search engine.
This method works for Internet Explorer but it seems that it doesn't work for Edge. Does anyone know why? Is there a different API to change the default search engine on Edge?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Microsoft Edge [does not currently support](http://textslashplain.com/2015/04/13/opensearch/) the OpenSearch API.  A request has been [logged to UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/7552719-add-opensearch-addsearchprovider-back-to-spartan-l), but that seems to be the end of it.  As of this writing, there have been no updates on the request nor is the API listed in the [modern.ie roadmap](https://status.modern.ie/?term=search) page.

Also, it's worth mentioning that since MS Edge does not support ActiveX controls, it will not support the C++ extensibility calls.  There's not a lot of information currently available on the new model, only that it's similar to Chrome's.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance